# Draw Polygon and evaluate pixels

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to use GPU acceleration (DirectX/C++) to draw polygon on 2D image.

After drawing is complete I want to loop through all pixel and evaluate them to get "score" of final/generated image (compare to targeted Image). Final score should be then return from GPU.

I know there is big overhead from reading from GPU, but I want rendering speed of GPU instead of CPU (GDI+ or openCV).

I am doing something similar to [EvoLisa](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/12/16/evolisa-optimizations-and-improved-quality/).

What would be best approach to achieve this?

Score is currently evaluated as follows:

```
// Render image
cv::Mat generatedImage = EvoRenderer::render(individual, heigth, width, dimension, corners, parameters);

// Evaluate generated image
double* colors = new double[generatedImage.channels()];
for (int i = 0; i < generatedImage.channels(); ++i) {
    colors[i] = double(0.0);
}
for (int j = 0; j < this->heigth; ++j)
    for (int i = 0; i < this->width; ++i)
    {           
        RGB& targetRGB = targetImage.ptr<RGB>(j)[i];
        RGB& generatedRGB = generatedImage.ptr<RGB>(j)[i];

        colors[0] += fabs(targetRGB.blue - generatedRGB.blue);
        colors[1] += fabs(targetRGB.green - generatedRGB.green);
        colors[2] += fabs(targetRGB.red - generatedRGB.red);
    }

long double error = 0;
const double divider = 255.0 * this->width * this->heigth;
for (int i = 0; i < generatedImage.channels(); i++)
    error += colors[i] / divider;
error *= double(100.0);

// Set fitnes to current individual
individual.setEval(error);

// Delete pointers
delete[] colors;
```

Comment: How exactly does the computation of this "score" work? If you're really just drawing a single polygon, then the overhead of reading back all the pixels just so you can "evaluate" them on the CPU would almost certainly outweigh any potential benefit from doing the drawing using the GPU by a large margin. In fact, the overhead of just invoking the GPU at all will likely already outweigh any potential gains if we're talking about just a single polygon…

Comment: Score is evaluated by looping through all pixels on all the channels and comparing that to targeted image. Basically we are comparing two image and getting difference. 
It will not be only a single polygon, but multiply polygons (1000+)

Comment: Currently my code is like 70%-80% in render() method, so I guess my current bottleneck is rendering polygons

Comment: You could easily perform this difference computation on the GPU too. Unfortunately, it's really hard to say much more without knowing more about what it is that you're actually trying to achieve…

Comment: Exactly I would just need difference computation score from GPU.

I am trying to achieve something like this: https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/

Comment: The fact that you're talking about a "score", however, tells me that there's more to it than just subtracting two images. I guess you'll also want to accumulate, probably the squared distances!? Would all be possible to do on a modern GPU, but I'm afraid an explanation of how to do that will not fit into a comment. And first of all, we would still need a clear and detailed description of what exactly you're trying to achieve…